# How to limit data length to cell width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid where sometimes the description's data is more than the cell width and then it wraps and I don't want that to happen, I would like to just show enough data in the cell and add an ellipsis at the end of the data and add a tooltip to show the remainder of the data, which I can figure out on my own, just not sure how to limit the data to the cells width. The column in question is 200px

Here is what it currently looks like

[image: Current]

and this is how I would like it to look

[image: Wanted]

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @NagaSaiA, I would provide code if I knew where to start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478693/10761855 if you need, i can add js code for you resolve your problem, but i need time for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

```css
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
  max-width: 200px:
}
```

```html
<td class="cell ellipsis">
  text inside cell
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using **max-width** and **text-overflow: ellipsis**

```css
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
  max-width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Custom size wall corner single entry</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Text-overflow works only for block level elements, so to make it work for table cell add max-width to apply the ellipsis( td is by default with **display: table-cell**)

As per MDN, *The text-overflow property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RmmmKK

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, text-overflow: ellipsis doesnt work directly on table cell unless used with max-width for td, text-overflow : ellipsis is common from Paul's answer but max-width is missing